# Hapijs throws 'cannot throw non-error object error' when returning data from level db in Node

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, leveldb

I have been struggling figuring this out:

Trying to: Return data from levelDB on a GET request in Hapijs. 
But getting:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    Error: Cannot throw non-error object
    at module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (.../node_modules/hapi/lib/toolkit.js:42:33)
    at <anonymous>
```

There shouldn't be an error in the first place. Retrieving the data in a Node REPL environment works fine. Putting data in the DB via POST request works fine as well.

LevelDB helper functions to get and retrieve data:

```
/** Helper functions to interact with the address levelDB */

const level = require('level');
const addressDB = './adressdata';
const db = level(addressDB);

function addAddressToDB(address) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject ) => {
    db.put(address.toString(), 'valid')
      .then( () => resolve('Stored Address.'))
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

// Checks how many stars an address still can create
function getAddressInfo(address) {
  return new Promise( (reject, resolve) => {
    db.get(address.toString())
      .then(value => resolve(value))
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

module.exports = {
  addAddressToDB: addAddressToDB,
  getAddressInfo: getAddressInfo
};
```

Hapijs server configuration:

```
'use strict';

// Basic server setup
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const addressDB = require('./addressdb-utilities');

const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 8000,
    host: 'localhost'
});
// Helper to Add Address
  server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/addAddress',
    config: {
      handler: async (request, response) => {
        try {
          let address = request.payload.address;
          let response = await addressDB.addAddressToDB(address, 'valid')

          return response;
        } catch(err) { throw new Error(err) }
      }
    }
  });

  // Helper to retrieve address
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/address/{address}',
    handler: async (request, h) => {
      let address = encodeURIComponent(request.params.address);
      let status = await addressDB.getAddressInfo(address); // This line causes the error
      console.log('Address: ', address);
      console.log('Address Type: ', typeof address);
      console.log(status);
      return 'status';
    }
  });
// Initialize server
const init = async () => {
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
    return;

};

// Error handling
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Wrapping everything in a try/catch blog leads to no error message on the server but a code 500 response on request. Just resolving for err and value also doesn't change anything.

I'm very grateful for every hint into more debugging, things to try aso. I'm out of ideas and research didn't help so far. Hopefully you find all information provided here.

Environment:

- Node version: 8.11.3
- Hapi version: 17.5.3
- Level version: 4.0.0
- OS:OSX 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging for many, many hours. I realized that the promise params where in the wrong order... so reject resolved and the other way around.

Comment: what are the chances, I did the same thing, had the params named the wrong way around. thanks